# MongoDB updating array object within an array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

**Model structure:**

```
{ _id: String, calc: [ { preset: String, datasets: [ { _id: String } ] } ] }
```

**API route:**

```
router.put('/:gameId/:preset/:datasetId', (req, res) => {
  Game.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.params.gameId, 'calc.preset': req.params.preset, 'calc.datasets._id': req.params.datasetId },
    { $set: { 'calc.$.datasets.$': req.body } })
    .then(() => res.status(200).json({ ...req.body, _id: req.params.datasetId }))
    .catch(err => res.status(500).json({ error: err }));
});
```

If I was to update an object inside calc array then I would: `$set: { 'calc.$': newCalc }`, so I followed the same approach in order to update an object that is inside datasets array, that is inside an object, that is inside calc array, however, `$set: { 'calc.$.datasets.$': newDataset }` doesn't work.

How to update an object with _id: req.params.datasetId, inside datasets array, that is inside calc array's object where the preset: req.params.preset?

*In short:* `{ calc: [ { datasets: [ { set this object to a new dataset } ] } }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `$[]` [positional-all](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/) to updated nested array elements, mongo doc for [$[]](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/#update-nested-arrays-in-conjunction-with-identifier)

query

```
db.t14.update(
   {},
   { $set: { "calc.$[].datasets.$[elem].name": "updated" } },
   { arrayFilters: [  { "elem": "x1" } ], multi: true}
)
```

sample collection with a document

```
> db.t14.findOne()
{
        "_id" : 1,
        "calc" : [
                {
                        "preset" : "abc",
                        "datasets" : [
                                {
                                        "_id" : "x1",
                                        "name" : "n1"
                                },
                                {
                                        "_id" : "x2",
                                        "name" : "n2"
                                }
                        ]
                }
        ]
}
```

update

```
> db.t14.update({},{$set: { "calc.$[].datasets.$[elem].name": "newname" } },{ arrayFilters: [{ "elem.name": "n1" }], multi: true})
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 1 })
```

post update

```
> db.t14.findOne()
{
        "_id" : 1,
        "calc" : [
                {
                        "preset" : "abc",
                        "datasets" : [
                                {
                                        "_id" : "x1",
                                        "name" : "newname"
                                },
                                {
                                        "_id" : "x2",
                                        "name" : "n2"
                                }
                        ]
                }
        ]
}
>
```